# Cmake error when installing beginner_tutorials/package

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the below tutorials for ROS and am creating a ROS package but am running into issues.
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and kinetic kame.

I have entered the following commands in order:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
```

I am receiving no errors when creating the catkin package, but when I use the catkin_make command I get a CMake error as below:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pocketsphinx" with
  any of the following names:

    pocketsphinxConfig.cmake
    pocketsphinx-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pocketsphinx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "pocketsphinx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "pocketsphinx" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  gaitech_edu-master/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'pocketsphinx'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pocketsphinx" with
  any of the following names:

    pocketsphinxConfig.cmake
    pocketsphinx-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pocketsphinx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "pocketsphinx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "pocketsphinx" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  gaitech_edu-master/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jamescoady/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jamescoady/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:2628: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Has anyone come accross this issue before?

I have installed the pocketsphinx using the follwing commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install pocketsphinx
```

This installs with no issues but when I use 'catkin make' I get the same error as above.

**Update**
I have also tried to install python pcketsphinx using the below commands. But when I try catkin_make again I still get the same errors as above.

```
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-pocketsphinx
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351067/cmake-error-when-installing-beginner_tutorials/package/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-01**:
It's more likely CMake is looking for the (old) [pocketsphinx](http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx) ROS package.

However, if you've just installed ROS, this doesn't make much sense.

Can you please include the output of `ls -al ~/catkin_ws/src`?

**Comment by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on 2020-05-01**:
Hi gvdhoorn,

Below is the output:

> jamescoady@jamescoady-Inspiron-5579:~$ ls -al ~/catkin_ws/src

> total 40

> drwxrwxr-x 10 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 30 15:47 .

> drwxrwxr-x  5 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 30 15:52 ..

> drwxrwxr-x  4 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 30 15:52 beginner_tutorials

> lrwxrwxrwx  1 jamescoady jamescoady   50 Nov  1 12:36 CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

> drwx------  3 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 29 10:56 gaitech_edu-master

> drwxrwxr-x 12 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Jan 31 12:41 raspicam_node

> drwxrwxr-x  4 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Dec 18 09:18 ros_tutorials_topic

> drwxrwxr-x 10 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 23 08:55 turtlebot3

> drwxrwxr-x  9 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Jan 30 10:45 turtlebot3_applications

> drwxrwxr-x  5 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Jan 30 10:45 turtlebot3_applications_msgs

> drwxrwxr-x  4 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 23 08:53 turtlebot3_msgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Hi gvdhoorn,
>
> Below is the output:
>
> ```
> jamescoady@jamescoady-Inspiron-5579:~$ ls -al ~/catkin_ws/src
> total 40
> drwxrwxr-x 10 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 30 15:47 .
> drwxrwxr-x  5 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 30 15:52 ..
> drwxrwxr-x  4 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 30 15:52 beginner_tutorials
> lrwxrwxrwx  1 jamescoady jamescoady   50 Nov  1 12:36 CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
> drwx------  3 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 29 10:56 gaitech_edu-master
> drwxrwxr-x 12 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Jan 31 12:41 raspicam_node
> drwxrwxr-x  4 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Dec 18 09:18 ros_tutorials_topic
> drwxrwxr-x 10 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 23 08:55 turtlebot3
> drwxrwxr-x  9 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Jan 30 10:45 turtlebot3_applications
> drwxrwxr-x  5 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Jan 30 10:45 turtlebot3_applications_msgs
> drwxrwxr-x  4 jamescoady jamescoady 4096 Apr 23 08:53 turtlebot3_msgs
> ```

it seems you have quite a few other packages in your workspace.

Your problems are not with the `beginner_tutorials`, but with one of those other packages.

I would suggest to:

- either solve the problem with those other packages
- create a new workspace and follow the tutorials with that new workspace, or
- move the packages which are in your current workspace to some temporary location so you only keep the `beginner_tutorials` package

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on 2020-05-01**:
This worked.

I made a temporary folder for the following:

Gaitech edu_master

raspicam_node

ros_tutorials_topis

turtlebot3

turtlebot3_msgs

turtlebot3_applications

turtlebot3_applications_msgs

I then ran catkin_make again with no error.

I was not aware of problems with the other packages but I will begin to look into that.

Thanks for your help.